# How to access return value from user-space probing with systemtap

Tags: systemtap

I want to access data that return from "open" function of glibc such as filename or file descriptor

I try

```
probe process("/lib*/libc.so.*").function("open") { 
   fd = $fd
   filename = user_string($filename)
   printf("%d %d %s %s\n",pid(),ppid(),filename,fd)
}
```

but it error

> semantic error: unresolved target-symbol expression: identifier '$fd'
>   at malloc.stp:3:10
>           source:         fd = $fd
>                                ^
>
> Pass 2: analysis failed.  [man error::pass2]

Answer (score 6):

The `open` system call does not take an `fd` argument, so a `.function` probe naturally won't find it.  If you'd like to see the file descriptor **returned from** `open`, then probe the `.function("...").return` point, and `$return`.

```
probe process("/lib*/libc.so.6").function("open").return {
    fd=$return
    path=user_string(@entry(@choose_defined($file,$filename)))
    printf("open %s -> %d\n", path, fd)
}
```

(Added the `@choose_defined()` here because some versions of glibc have renamed this parameter.)

Comment: I have tried your example, but I always receive a "semantic error: unresolved target-symbol expression: identifier '$filename'". Do you know why this happens?

Comment: Maybe your installation is lacking access to glibc debuginfo?

Comment: In glibc v2.37, this variable has been renamed:


`% stap -L 'process("/lib*/libc.so.6").function("open")'`
`process("/usr/lib/libc.so.6").function("__libc_open@../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/open.c:31") $file:char const* $oflag:int` `process("/usr/lib64/libc.so.6").function("__libc_open64@../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/open64.c:29") $file:char const* $oflag:int`